# View controller that specifies which path to show depending on authentication

Tags: grails, controller

I have a website, with an admin account that uploads to a specific path some files, and then the user after authenticating the password for a specific path, he can see the files

This is the admin account: He can upload new files to paths. Also he can create new path with a click of a button.

[image]

The user enters a password that we the admins give him, so he can access specific type of files, that we uploaded. as shown in the picture below:[image]

I do not want the user1 to be able to see path2 or user2 to be able to see path1.

How do I do that ?

I currently have a **Document** controller that succesfully uploads files for the admin, also I have a **login** controller that authenticate the access. only thing I need is to understand what variables I need to define in my domain class and what function to use on it in the controller to be able to complete my view tasks above

This is my class domain

```
package file_down

class Document {
    String filename
    byte[] filedata
    Date uploadDate = new Date()
    //String Path ??  >> if so what functions to use with it

    static constraints = {
        filename(blank: false, nullable:false)
        filedata(blank: true, nullable: true, maxSize:1073741824)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like maybe you've overcomplicated things a bit? If you want to lock down paths per user, you should define a Domain to do so. Something like:

```
class UserPath {
  User user
  Path path
}
```

It's basically a simple many-to-many. When the admin creates a new path, he should decide which users have access to said path. Now, you can present a user with her available Paths and if they try and access one from the URL, you check if the authenticated user has access to said Path via the UserPath table.

Comment: Would that domain be different from the domain class (Document) I have ?

Comment: It depends. If many users can "own / have access to" a document and when you say path, you also mean document, it could be a composite m2m table and it would work. If many documents can live in the same path, then it might not work if you want to restrict access to just the path.